# regarding print out os.environ variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a code segment in one Python program. It runs fine.

```
if 'TV_DIR_RUNS' in os.environ:
    os.environ['TV_DIR_RUNS'] = os.path.join(os.environ['TV_DIR_RUNS'],'Seg')
```

I was trying to take a look at `os.environ['TV_DIR_RUNS']`, by adding a `print` function.

```
if 'TV_DIR_RUNS' in os.environ:
    os.environ['TV_DIR_RUNS'] =    os.path.join(os.environ['TV_DIR_RUNS'],'KittiSeg')
print(os.environ['TV_DIR_RUNS'])
```

Then running the program generates the following error message

```
File "train.py", line 107, in main
print(os.environ['TV_DIR_RUNS'])
File "/devl/lib/python3.4/os.py", line 635, in __getitem__
raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'TV_DIR_RUNS'
```

This really confuses me, because it seems to me that `os.environ['TV_DIR_RUNS'] =    os.path.join(os.environ['TV_DIR_RUNS'],'KittiSeg')` can be executed successfully, why it cannot be printed out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find that `'TV_DIR_RUNS'` is not in `os.environ`. Change your line to `print(os.environ.get('TV_DIR_RUNS'))`

The line `os.environ['TV_DIR_RUNS'] = ...` is inside the block of the if statement, checking if `'TV_DIR_RUNS'` is in `os.environ`.